# Check magento 'No_image' value?

Tags: magento

I added an extra image attribute called **'Specification'**  along with (**Base Image, Small Image,Thumbnail**).

I want to find out if the 'specification' has **no_image** option box ticked. I tried quite a few things but nothing helped me (**PHP**). It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: I tried  if($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'specification')) == no_selection

Comment: try out `$_product->getSpecification2() == 'no_selection'`

Comment: Nope it doesn't do anything. Shouldn't we have a function called getSpecification() for this??

Comment: Yoy have specified Specification2 in your condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_product->getSpecification2() == 'no_selection' Works